# Less won't compile as nodejs middleware

Tags: node.js, less

I setup less-middleware for compiling less on the fly, it worked great for quite some time now, but I was changing some packages, doing npm update and so on, but nothing really less-related...

And it stopped working. When I'm requesting for example main.css (it should compile main.less and serve it as css), I get weird error in console:

```
LESS Syntax error : Object function (deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
} has no method 'charAt'
  LESS File : /srv/sicy-node/public/css/main.less null:-1
TypeError: Object function (deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
} has no method 'charAt'
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.ruleProperty (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1938:37)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.rule (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1479:48)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.primary (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:721:76)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.block (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1427:51)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.ruleset (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1461:48)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.primary (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:721:91)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.block (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1427:51)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.directive (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:1715:34)
at Object.Parser.parser.parsers.parsers.primary (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:722:64)
at Object.Parser.parser.parse [as parse] (/srv/sicy-node/node_modules/less-middleware/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:498:61)
```

This is how middleware is set:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as it was problem with permissions. I've just set new permissions and everything works fine again. So if anyone have same problem be sure that less can create new file and that original less is readable by your app.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Edit: Problem can also occur if you are using **@import url("something.less")**, try dropping url part: **@impurt "something.less"**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a result of [that bug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1840) in Less 1.6.1 (basically, Less fails if some other module extends `Array.prototype`). Updating `less-middleware` to more recent Less version should help (you can update your installation by changing the version in [this file](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/blob/master/package.json#L12) to `~1.6.3` if it does not update automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I might not be solving your exact problem but this is how i do the **less** compilation using **grunt**, infact not just i but most of the people do, and i find it very convenient.

[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) provides a great way to automate the process of transmuting **LESS** into **CSS**. Initially you'll have to set up a few tools, but once you're done with that, you can easily use the system with all your projects.

**Grunt is a JavaScript-based task runner** that can be configured to keep an eye on changes made to your LESS files. When the contents change, it automatically compiles the files into a minified CSS file.

**Step 1: Install Node.js**
Get the installation package from [**Nodejs.com**](http://nodejs.org/), and install it. Binaries are available for Mac OS X, Windows, Linux, and SunOS. You can also compile it from source code.

**Step 2: Install Grunt**
Install Grunt using the Node package manager:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

**Step 3: Write your Grunt configuration file**

Create a Gruntfile.js file in your project directory. Then copy and paste the contents below. You'll just need to change the (commented) lines that define which files you want Grunt to watch, and where to place the compiled CSS file.

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {
          grunt.initConfig({
             less: {
              development: {
                    options: {
                         compress: true,
                         yuicompress: true,
                         optimization: 2
                      },
                     files: {
                         // target.css file: source.less file
                          "sites/all/themes/jiandan/css/main.css": "sites/all/themes /jiandan/less/main.less"
                           }
                }
             },
      watch: {
         styles: {
                // Which files to watch (all .less files recursively in the less   directory)
             files: ['sites/all/themes/jiandan/less/**/*.less'],
             tasks: ['less'],
             options: {
                nospawn: true
               }
       }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

**Step 4: Configure the package**

```
cd YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY
npm init
```

The above will prompt you to supply additional information about your project.

When you're done, open the **package.json** file located in your project directory, and add the following lines of code:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "grunt": "~0.4.1",
   "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.5.0",
   "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0"
```

},

Then issue the following command to install the package dependencies:

```
npm install
```

**Step 5: Start Grunt**

```
grunt
```

Well that's it and you can compile all your less in one shot.
I agree that initially it looks complicated but once you get used to it, you are going to find it very simple. All you need to do is create a configuration file for each project, and Grunt will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this soon! I just found out the problem (Will post as self answer)